# Rails, Arel, Ransack: sort_by sum of relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel, ransack

```
class Document
  has_many :lines
end

class Line
  belongs_to :document
end

sort_by @q, :total
```

Hello, I need to sort documents by the sum of their lines (amount column in lines).

I thought about a ransacker but how to write it properly?

```
ransacker :total do
  parent ???
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider computing the total number of lines after_create and after_destroy of any `Line` object and storing this in a `line_count` column on `documents`. This will make querying significantly faster, and lays the data out easy to see. Look into [Rails counter caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference) too, which implements this without you having to think about all the callbacks yourself.

However you can also do this with a ransacker by using COUNT and GROUP BY. Here's a quick one:

```
  ransacker :line_count do
    query = "(SELECT COUNT(lines.id) FROM lines WHERE lines.document_id = documents.id GROUP BY lines.document_id)"
    Arel.sql(query)
  end
```

Comment: To give you an example, on my application's db, an equivalent query took 4.5 seconds to get the first record sorted by count descending. This db has over a million rows in each of the joining tables, but it illustrates the problem. If you store the count of lines in the `documents` table, the query is both easy to understand and extremely fast.

Comment: I have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984939/ransack-sort-on-count-of-habtm-or-hmt-associated-records) somewhat related question with a bounty. Would you like to take a crack at it?